# Serializing / Deserializing Java classes to and from JSON

Tags: java, json

I'm new to Java EE development although I've been doing Android development for years. In Android I use Google Gson to serialize or deserialize Java classes. Is this the most popular way of doing this for Java EE development or should I be looking at some other API that is more suitable for this platform?

Comment: `GSON` is perfectly fine :)

Comment: This seems like an opinion based question. Have a look at Jackson parser.

Comment: Gson is definitely an option. Slightly more standard, jaxb can also do json and is included out of the box

Comment: @ManuViswam Not entirely. If Google GSON were to have problems running on Java EE, I'd like to know about that, rather than assuming that if it works in Android, it will work in Java EE. If a developer is developing for both Android and Java EE, it would be nice to use a consistent API when dealing with JSON.

Comment: @AndroidDev `Is this the most popular way of doing this` sounds a bit like opinion though.

Comment: @AndroidDev : in that case fasterxml jackson is definitely a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

Gson is good library for Java EE.

We use gson on production environment without problems.